# Spring JDBC pool connection always max

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jdbc, pool

We have a problem on a production server, this server is querying an external database (Postgresql)
We have set the Max pool size to 20 and min pool size to 5, but we have always 20 open connection on Postgresql server even if it does not require that much connection, and almost all connexions are idle during 2 hours or more.
The problem : we have 4 instances of this application, so we have 80 open connection on this external database

This is our configuration :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<datasources>
  <local-tx-datasource>
    <jndi-name>jdbc/name</jndi-name>
    <connection-url>
        [CONNECTION_URL]
    </connection-url>
    <driver-class>org.postgresql.Driver</driver-class>
    <user-name>[USER_DB]</user-name>
    <password>[PWD_DB]</password>
    <min-pool-size>5</min-pool-size>
    <max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size>
     <valid-connection-checker-class-name>org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.postgres.PostgreSQLValidConnectionChecker</valid-connection-checker-class-name>
    <exception-sorter-class-name>
        org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.postgres.PostgreSQLExceptionSorter
    </exception-sorter-class-name>
  </local-tx-datasource>
</datasources>
```

The default timeout for idle connection is 30 if not set.
So why they are so many unused (idle) connections ?

Thanks

Comment: 30 what? seconds, millis, hours. Also make sure you have configured checking for idle connections not sure if that tis on by default.

Comment: 15 minutes not 30 sorry, 
I don't see anything to check idle connections in the configuration : https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/ConfigDataSources?_sscc=t It should work with only these parameters